# Why are some OSM GPX line string endpoints connected?

Tags: convert, geojson, linestring, gpx

I am working with [GPX files from OpenStreetMap](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Berlin_U-Bahn) to render the public transportation lines of Berlin. I converted them to [GeoJSON](https://github.com/johnjohndoe/RROK/tree/master/assets) using the [togeojson script](https://github.com/mapbox/togeojson). For **some** reason some of the lines are rendered as a "circle". The first and the last point are connected for some reason. The effect can be seen at the GitHub project I linked.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which of the 20+ geojson files are we meant to look at to see the problem?

Comment: @BradHards [U5](https://github.com/johnjohndoe/RROK/blob/master/assets/u5.geojson) for example.

Comment: The data is probably what the GPS receiver recorded, but because the U-Bahn doesn't provide very good GPS environment, the receiver goes into dead-reckoning mode. Its hard to say without looking at the source data and knowing exactly how it was recorded.

Comment: @BradHards I linked the data source. It is OpenStreetMap. I took the GPX files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gpx files made of Openstreetmap data only have limited use. All way segments are simply concatenated in the sequence of the way IDs. That does not make much sense.

There is not yet any tool that puts the segments together in a logical way.

The workaround I use is to load the original data (the XML link) into JOSM editor, and join the way elements to a single line, and export that. Beware not to upload on leaving JOSM!!!

Comment: How exactly can I open the XML link in JOSM (which menu item)? I have the server running on port 8011 so the application reacts when I click the JOSM link. However nothing shows up. Sry, I just did my first steps using JOSM.

Comment: `File -> Open` is the usual way. I never use the JOSM link. Alternatively you can copy the relation ID to clipboard, then `File -> Download Object` with Object Type `Relation`. If you see nothing, have a look at the Relation window. You might have to reload the relation elements.

Comment: That works good very good with `Join Node to Way`. Can you tell if there is a way how I can **exclude the station names** and just export the line itself?

Comment: `File - New Layer`, then go back to your first Layer, select the line and `Edit -> Merge selection`.

Comment: `Merge selection` requires to `Select All` before. This also selects the points. How can I select just the line which I created before in the join step?

Comment: You can select a single line by clicking at it. The points of the line will obviously be chosen too.